# Kendo UI - stoping binding for part of the View

Tags: kendo-ui

I have complex View that is composed of different parts. I need to bind some parts of it manually to a ViewModel that is different than the one for the View itself. Currently, Kendo UI is processing all elements of the View for the main binding - is there any way to instruct it to skip some elements like Knockout does?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how unbind some element but you can use kendo layout and as many views as you want. Each view can have its own view-model. It is clear and flexible solution.

```
<div id="app"></div>


<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="layout-template">
    <h1 data-bind="text: heading"></h1>

    <div id="view1-container"></div>
    <div id="view2-container"></div>
</script>


<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="sub-view1-template">
    <p data-bind="text: text1"></p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="sub-view2-template">
    <p data-bind="text: text2"></p>
</script>



<script>

    var layoutViewModel = kendo.observable({
       heading: 'Layout heading'
    });
    var view1ViewModel = kendo.observable({
        text1: 'Text from view-model 1'
    });
    var view2ViewModel = kendo.observable({
        text2: 'Text from view-model 2'
    });


    var mainLayout = new kendo.Layout('layout-template', { model: layoutViewModel});

    var view1 = new kendo.View('sub-view1-template', {model: view1ViewModel});
    var view2 = new kendo.View('sub-view2-template', {model: view2ViewModel});

    mainLayout.render($("#app"));

    mainLayout.showIn('#view1-container', view1);
    mainLayout.showIn('#view2-container', view2);
</script>
```

Comment: It is much more complex. This is LOB application, where HTML represents data from multiple source and has to be formatted based on a business needs and not convenience of the developer. As such, different Views are mixed together in a DOM. The problem is not a logical Views, but physical representation of the View in a DOM - once Kendo binding is applied to a View - it will affect all HTML elements contained by it, even if they are from different logical Views. Again, Knockout allows stopping binding propagation, but Kendo does not (this is already confirmed by their tech support).